# Can I accept an answer if my question has been marked as duplicate?

Tags: support

[image: Answer to "Duplicate question"]Can I accept an answer if my question has been marked as duplicate?

If so, how? I noticed there is no "check mark" next to the answer that I found usefull (more so than the similar question where I was told I should find my answer)

[image: Stackexchange user21569]

Comment: If you're referring to [that specific question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/33178/10): It was posted by "user21568" so you would have to be logged in as that user to see the Accept button.

Comment: @feetwet : I am user 21569 (please see photo I added to the question). I don't know why that question comes up under user21568. Any idea ?

Comment: You should use the "[Contact](https://law.stackexchange.com/contact)" link to send a message to the CMs asking them to merge the two user accounts.  That should get you squared away!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can.** There's nothing to stop the asker to accept an existing answer *on their own questions* regardless if they're closed or not.

However, you can't accept any answer on questions not owned/asked by you.

On the other hand, *feel free to upvote any answers that are helpful to you*.